# Is it possible to run gitk in cloud9

Tags: linux, cloud9-ide, gitk

I get the following when trying to run gitk in cloud9-ide

```
application-specific initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Error in startup script: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
    while executing
"load /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.so Tk"
    ("package ifneeded Tk 8.6.1" script)
    invoked from within
"package require Tk"
    (file "/usr/bin/gitk" line 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gitk is a visual git tool and Cloud9 doesn't have a gui, only a terminal. So unfortunately they're not going to work together. You could try using tig, which is visual but works with the Cloud9 terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ssh connection open in the background (like PUTTY) and you have XForwarding configured correctly on that connection. You can launch gitk from the cloud9 terminal.